# CDO tag rename request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) that using the meta is the way to request a tag rename request from a moderator.

I would like to suggest the renaming of the tag [cdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) to something specific to avoid confusion with [cdo-climate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo-climate) and [cdo.message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo.message).

These are the conflicting tags,the number of questions and their definition:

- [cdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) 42 questions (and decreasing!), 78 watchers: "*CDO is a free implementation of a Distributed Shared Model on top of the Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF)...*"
- [cdo-climate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo-climate) 220 questions, 30 watchers: "*Climate Data Operators (CDO) is a collection of command line Operators to manipulate and analyse gridded datasets in the supported data formats of netCDF 3/4...*"
- [cdo.message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo.message)  215 questions, 1 watcher: "*Part of Microsoft's Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) it is usually used by WSH or .NET applications for e-mail message automation.*"

I actually set up the cdo-climate tag, and I regularly have to edit cdo-climate questions that are incorrectly tagged with cdo. I know there is the metadata, but it seems a lot of people don't read it. If the cdo tag could be renamed to something a bit more specific, I think it would it would avoid most of the mis-tagging.

Although it has 78 watchers, it seems to be a relatively rarely-used tag, with only 42 questions.  In fact it used to be well over 120 questions, but the majority of the questions were actually for cdo-climate, and after I sifted through and corrected the tags, that left 42 - and looking through them now I see that nearly all the remaining question are actually intended for cdo.message and there are probably very few questions intended for this "cdo.eclipse" topic.   (Indeed, I suspect that quite a few of those 78 watchers are likely interested in cdo-climate or cdo.message too by logical extension).

So as it is relatively obscure, I hope that the tag rename does not impact too many people.  I'm not sure what to suggest for new name, but perhaps **cdo.emf** or **cdo-eclipse**? (I used a hyphen instead of a dot in my tag, not sure what is considered the best etiquette). I am also happy to clean up the remaining incorrect tags between cdo and cdo.message.

*update*: After retagging all the cdo.message questions correctly, the actual [cdo] tag referring to eclipse only has 10 questions posted to it, the most recent of which was Jan 2018, nearly 4 years ago.  So this obscure and inactive tag is causing all the cdo.message and cdo-climate questions to be incorrectly tagged (with the exception of one question, which was a python question on manipulating "Collateralized Debt Obligation" financial instrument stats :-D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now made this change myself.  In case, this is helpful to others, there is a roundabout way I did not know of, which I found out in response to this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416359/what-can-you-do-if-a-tag-rename-request-is-not-adopted-by-a-moderator), which can allow you to make this change even without being a moderator:

1. Probably best to first post a tag rename request to see if it has the support of the community.
2. Then you can set up a new tag name and copy across the wiki info from the old tag, in this case I've created the tag [cdo-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo-emf)
3. You will then need to manually retag the questions that use the old tag, in my case this was only 11 questions, as the [cdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) tag was rarely used.
4. Apparently then the old tag will automatically be deleted after one day if it has no questions posted to it.

Note that in a couple of cases the retagging wasn't immediate, as the old questions had titles that failed the current quality control threshold and so the tag could not be made without revising the title.

@Tomerikoo makes a valid point in his comment that this does not move across watchers.  That is true, but I actually suspect in this case that the majority of watchers were actually interested in [cdo-climate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo-climate) and [cdo.message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo.message). When I came across this tag issue, I found that 230 out of 241 questions were mistagged, so I estimate that 95% of the 78 watchers were also watching the incorrect tag. Of the remaining 4 or 5 "true" watchers, I presume that they are not actively watching as the tag has not had a new question posted to it for over 4 years.

Comment: This sounds like a viable way to do that. One single caveat I can think of here is watchers. Unlikely plausible with such minor tags (I doubt there were even watchers for a 11 questions tag), but this is the only thing that I can think of that truly gets lost doing this. If there were watchers to the old tag they will not be aware that *"their"* tag was gone and replaced with another...

Comment: good point, I updated the answer to include a comment on watchers... in this case I think it is not a big issue as it is an inactive and obscure tag, but in other cases this could be an issue. thanks for pointing it out.