# What can you do if a tag rename request is not adopted by a moderator?

Tags: support, tags

I submitted a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412466/cdo-tag-rename-request) suggesting a tag name request for [cdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) a while back as the [cdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) tag for the rarely used (11 questions) eclipse is regularly misused to mark [cdo.message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo.message) and [cdo-climate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo-climate) questions (both 230+ questions) which I then usually correct (I signed up to email alerts for [cdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdo) for that purpose in fact).

Despite some upvotes, the suggestion has not been implemented yet, and so I presume it wasn't noticed by moderators, whom I suspect are extremely busy people with huge numbers of edits to take care of.  I was just wondering if there was a way of placing a tag rename request in a queue, a little like flagging a question on SO?  This is not a critical thing, just think it would be nice to clean up.  I wish I could implement it myself to save having to bother someone with it.

Comment: Take a look at some of the other retag requests that are status-completed. How many votes do they have? How long did it take for them to be processed?

Comment: I can find one at +16 (just like the one here) that took 1 day

Comment: "Despite some upvotes the suggestion was not implemented yet, and so I presume it wasn't noticed by moderators" - tag moderation has been neglected for a solid couple of years. Be patient, it takes time.

Comment: I'm happy to wait, I hope from the tone of my question that it was clear this was not a complaint in any way at all, I was just kind of presuming that if it slips under the radar for a few months it would no longer be picked up. So I was wondering if there was a way to know if the suggestion might have been "approved" so to speak and queued for implementation...

Comment: in fact thinking about it, maybe I should have put a question title of "how to know if your rename suggestion has been queued for implementation?" But I'm not even sure if such a system exists, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Some times is better to take action yourself, as you have taken, but in the other direction. Instead of removing from the ones that are invalid, create a valid one and migrate everything to it so that it isn't polluted by invalid uses. [emf-cdo] is a valid solution and you can apply it now.

Comment: @Braiam Good point, I did already wade through the site and retag over 200 historic questions that had incorrectly tagged with cdo, so I haven't been entirely passive in all this ;-) and you are correct that I could set up an cdo-emf tag and migrate the 11 cdo questions there, but I was worried I would make more mess by creating a synonym tag, and while the "cdo" tag still exists new questions will continue to be mistagged. Every sees "cdo" and thinks it is "their" cdo :-D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just starting by answering your title first:

> What can you do if a tag rename request is not adopted by a moderator?

Wait longer.

Yep, I do understand that it's been 6 months already, but there is a huge backlog of tag action requests that would need decades to handle. Some take 5 minutes, some take [5 years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/251105/revisions). The reason why there's such difference in handling times, is because the process is entirely manual. There is no way to signal to a moderator that there is this tag which needs attention, apart from them finding your post themselves. (There's one way, which is by pinging them on chat, but that depends on the mod). And even if they find it within a few seconds of you posting it, they might be reluctant to act on it, just to wait for community approval on it. That said, your assumption about it falling off the radar is a 100% accurate, though. Very few moderators visit the second page of the meta site. But, the assumption that it would never be picked up is wrong. There certainly are some moderators who do make it a point to clear up the tag requests backlog.

Now that that's out of the way, let me tell you why I suggest that you wait for tag rename requests, rather than get your hands down and dirty. There are a few reasons for this:

1. Tag renaming, is hands down the easiest task that a moderator can do with regards to the different tag actions. What they need to do is: 1. Go on the tag page and click on merge 2. Type the name of the new tag 3. Submit. This takes literally a few seconds to complete as opposed to us mortals taking days and days of work.
2. While manually renaming a tag, we need to edit a post and change the tag. This would cause needless bumping of the posts. Now, a lot of users might dismiss this, stating that on a site of the scale of Stack Overflow, bumping a post would result it in being on the homepage for a few seconds. However, the issue is that 1. It would take that spot from another perhaps more deserving post 2. For those who follow that tag, their homepage would be filled with just the old questions, hiding those newer ones which actually need to be answered.
3. Updating a tag manually, also means that you would need to copy over the tag wiki and the tag excerpt. This is simple if you have 20k reputation, as you would not need to wait in a queue, or else, you would need to again wait for your suggestion to be approved. Also, if mods rename the tag, the wiki would still be attributed to the original person who created it, and therefore, issues with plagiarism in the wiki itself would not involve you at all.
4. Finally, when you rename a tag manually, the old stub would still be left in place until the next day, which means that there is still a chance that someone might use that tag. You might feel that this is rare, but this does in fact happen quite often.

So, updating it manually does not have any benefits apart from being quick. While the process of waiting might be bitter, the rewards at the end of it are really sweet.

Anyway, as there are exceptions to everything, something that I suggest usually is, if there are a handful of questions with the tag, and if your post is quite old, then just go ahead and do it. You've posted the question on meta, so do go ahead and add an answer detailing what all actions that you took, and finally flag the post for a moderator to update the status tag. But remember to also migrate the tag wiki and the excerpt along with renaming the tags. In this particular case, do I suggest you to manually do it? No.

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav - I did already migrate 200+ mistagged cdo questions to cdo-climate and cdo.message.  I could set up an cdo-emf tag and migrate the 11 cdo questions there, but while the "cdo" tag still exists new questions will continue to be mistagged.  Would I then flag in my post that the cdo tag needs to be marked for deletion by a moderator to prevent ambiguities?

Comment: Tags with no posts would be automatically removed after a day.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that!  Okay already done! Thanks... had I known I would have done it without posting this, sorry to disturb everyone!