# Visual programming languages, placement drivers, & bamboo-eating bears in [pd]. Oh my!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) currently has a tag wiki excerpt which reads:

> PD is the abbreviation for Placement Driver, which is the managing component of TiDB. It is used to manage and schedule the TiKV cluster. PD supports distribution and fault-tolerance by embedding etcd.

Though in practice, it ends up on many [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) questions because of the common import alias:

```python
import pandas as pd
```

The tag appears on 57 questions.

### pandas

On [35 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd+pandas) it appears in addition to [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), there are also 10 pandas-related questions where it appears instead of [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68506417/15497888), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67316669/15497888), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67661483/15497888), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71322262/15497888), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68585929/15497888), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69195539/15497888), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71092188/15497888), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70832815/15497888), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69295780/15497888), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65465319/15497888)). For all of these questions, the tag [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) has no meaning and either should be replaced with [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) or removed.

### Pure Data

There is [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68848282/15497888) where [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) is used to mean [puredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puredata).

Note: the [puredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puredata) wiki excerpt and [their website](https://puredata.info/) support the usage of "Pd" as an "official" alias for Pure Data:

> Pd (aka Pure Data) is a real-time graphical programming environment for audio, video, and graphical processing.

(This has already been corrected.)

### TiDB Placement Drivers

There are 11 questions which use [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) with [tidb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidb)/[tikv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tikv) (inline with the tag wiki excerpt). ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49035036/15497888), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49422782/15497888), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49998283/15497888), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50287018/15497888), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50406685/15497888), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50441476/15497888), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50522675/15497888), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50755897/15497888), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51184366/15497888), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51490034/15497888), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59358982/15497888))

---

There is a currently pending [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/synonyms) which maps [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) to [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) which *might* make sense only in terms of actual usage of the tag, but does not fix the ambiguity of the tag.

There was already a [puredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puredata) tag which made it easy to fix that question, there is not a ready replacement for Placement Driver.

As TiDB Placement Drivers are outside my area of expertise, is there a reasonable replacement for [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) which is less ambiguous in meaning for these questions like [pd-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd-server) or [tidb-pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidb-pd) (as suggested by [Tom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3824919) [in the comments below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416565/visual-programming-languages-placement-drivers-bamboo-eating-bears-in-pd#comment899209_416565))?

It may also be worth noting that the last TiDB PD question was over 2 years ago, and the last [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) to mean [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) was 2 days ago (the majority of recent usage favours [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)).

Comment: Well, the most straightforward approach would be `tidb-pd`? And when "pd" is so ambiguous, then it shouldn't have an alias for only one of its meanings. I would rather be for blocking "pd" and maybe also add `panda-pd` if such tag is needed, but it currently doesn't look like it.

Comment: "There is a currently pending tag synonym which maps pd to pandas which might make sense" - it doesn't. It's two letters with no concrete meaning. "It's a common alias for an import" is a very weak synonym reason, when the first page of google alone gives me about 8 different meanings, and that's without clicking the wikipedia redirect page (and yikes, [it's extensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PD)). There's no value in keeping it -  [kill it with fire](https://c.tenor.com/Os-8-5BJTr0AAAAi/molly-jinzhan.gif): retag the TiDB questions, merge the rest into pandas and let the `pd` tag die

Comment: I agree on the synonym front. It wasn't my suggestion (noticing the pending synonym is what made me write this question). If the current `pd` tag were renamed `tidb-pd` then the tag wiki information would follow. Is it worth going the other way (_i.e._ fixing the pandas questions) to preserve that information? @ZoestandswithUkraine

Comment: Title suggestion: `import burnination as pd`

Comment: Get **rid** of it. It serves no purpose other than to leave 4 places for other tags instead of 5.

Comment: It's useless. pd is too vague for someone to infer what it means. Completely useless in practicality.

Comment: @HenryEcker We can merge in the tag wiki after the fact, assuming it passes all the other checks anyway. Retagging everything but the majority in a case like this saves us a lot of retagging, as those questions can get merged in. Nothing is lost by doing it this way if the tag wiki is handled before the merger.

Comment: Sounds good @ZoestandswithUkraine I wasn't sure what the mod tooling looked like in that regard and didn't want to lose anything important or run into plagiarism issues regarding the tag info.

Comment: Plagiarism isn't an issue when moving the tag wiki from one tag to another. It's a problem if it was plagiarized in the first place, but that's just cause to let it disappear. There's no mod tools for it, it's just using The Key:tm: to move  it from one tag to another.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I misunderstood what I read in [Bhargav's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416362). If someone copies over the tag wiki excerpt that was already plagiarized from another source then the plagiarism now (also) involves whoever copied over the tag info. On second look, that is exactly what it says I just misinterpreted it...

Comment: Unsurprisingly, several of those Pandas questions don't even have a python tag...

Comment: @HenryEcker  The tag wiki was plagiarized, FYI, so it won't be coming along to the new tag

Comment: Thank you for all your help @ZoestandswithUkraine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Summary of Discussion:

The tag [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) is [highly ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PD) and is not useful because of this and is better removed.

The tag [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) to mean [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) is redundant and serves no purpose. On these questions it is better replaced with the appropriate tag [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) or removed if used in addition to [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas). (This can be easily handled by merging [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) into [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) after retagging the TiDB questions)

For questions related to Pure Data the tag [puredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puredata) should be used.

For questions related to TiDB Placement Drivers the tag [tidb-pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidb-pd) should be used.

---

### Actions Taken:

1. The tag [tidb-pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidb-pd) has been created.
2. The TiDB Placement Driver questions were retagged with [tidb-pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidb-pd)
3. [pd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pd) was merged into [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)

Comment: But what happened to the bears?

Comment: I'd hope they're chuffed that their 10 waylaid siblings have been united with the rest of the group. @CodyGray